# route to async component wrapped with suspense warned expecting single root node

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

The route looks like this:

```
export default {
    path: "/lv1",
    component: () => import("./Lv1.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "lv2_1",
        component: () => import("./Lv21.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "lv2_2",
        component: () => import("./Lv22.vue"),
      },
    ...
    ]
}
```

`<Lv1 />` is a sync component and it looks like this:

```
<template>
    <RouterView v-slot="{Component}">
        <KeepAlive>
            <Suspense>
                <component :is="Component"/>
            </Suspense>
        </KeepAlive>
    </RouterView>
</template>
```

`<Lv21 />` and `<Lv22 />` are async components. `<Lv1 />` is also kept alive inside a router view.
When switching away from `<Lv1 />`(kept alive) the console warned this:

```
[Vue warn]: <Suspense> slots expect a single root node. 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <Lv1 onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< null > > 
  at <KeepAlive include="Lv1" > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

`<KeepAlive>` and `<Suspense>` work when switching back to `<Lv1 />` but there's warning every time I switch away from it.

I've looked at the document for `<Suspense>`: https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html#combining-with-other-components and I believe the ordering is correct.
I tried to wrap `<Lv21>` and `<Lv22>` with  and create a new component for it, like `<Lv21WithSuspense>` and route to that component. This time no more warnings, but that can't be the proper way to solve this, can it?

Answer (score 0):

From the [document](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html#combining-with-other-components) ,it says: The  component has two slots: #default and #fallback. Both slots only allow for one immediate child node, so you need keep your components(Lv21 and Lv22) only have one child node

Comment: sure thing. I have replace all the contents in the `<template>` tag with a single `<p>` tag, but problem persists.